# T Test 2 tail in python

Tags: python, t-test, hypothesis-test

My question is: 
How t-statistic and p value are calculated in formula stats.ttest_1samp() python ? 
There is a gap between formula results and my manual calculation which cause to opposite answers.

**example:** 
A claim, coin isn't fair.

observations = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]   
μ = 0.5 
α = 0.05 (confidence level 95%)

H0 : p=0.5   ,coin is fair 
H1: p != 0.5 , coin isn't fair

**Formula:**  
input: stats.ttest_1samp(observations,0.5)  
output: t_statistic = 2.25 , p_value = 0.051 
t_critic = 2.26 (df=9, 2 side tail 95%)        
result : (t_statistic  < t_critic) & (p_value > α) => Accept H0

**Manual calculation:**
input: 
x= np.mean(observations) = 0.8 
μ = 0.5 
n=10 
σ = np.std(observations) = 0.4 
T_statistic = input: (x-μ)/(σ/√n) => (0.8-0.5)/(0.4/√10) => 2.37

output 
t_statistic = 2.37, p_value = 0.0089 (p_value according Z table for 2.37) 
t_critic = 2.26 (degree of freedom=9, 2 side tail 95%) 
result : (t_statistic  >  t_critic) & (p_value < α) => Reject H0

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of the sample standard deviation [needs `ddof=1`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.std.html), the "Bessel correction" for bias:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
x = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0]

std = np.std(x, ddof=1)
m = np.mean(x)
m0 = 0.5
res = (m - m0)/(std/np.sqrt(len(x)))
# 2.2500000000000004
ref = stats.ttest_1samp(x, m0).statistic
# 2.2500000000000004
```

A much more appropriate test for such a small sample is the [binomial test](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binomtest.html).

```
stats.binomtest(sum(x), len(x), 0.5)
# BinomTestResult(k=8, n=10, alternative='two-sided', statistic=0.8, pvalue=0.109375)
```

After all, your sample was drawn from a binomial distribution, not a normal distribution.